# How to apply numbers in an array to existing DIVs on the page

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

This seems like it should be super simple, but I keep running into a wall.

Basically, I have 6 DIVs and 6 numbers in an array. (The number of DIVs and the number of items in the array will always be the same.)

The numbers are all percentages, displayed as numbers between 0 and 100. I want to set the width of each DIV sequentially based on the numbers in the array.

So, if my array is `[50,25,100,75,100,25]`, then the DIVs should be 50% wide, 25% wide, 100% wide, and so on, in order.

I think my code is like 90% there, but I'm obviously missing something. Markup for purposes of the illustration is just 6 empty DIVs.

My code is:

```
var percentages = [50,25,100,75,100,25];

$.each(percentages, function() {
    $('div').width(this + '%');
});
```

And here's my JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jkt5w/

Comment: What it currently does, by the way, is just apply the last number in the array to all of the DIVs. I get that this is because I haven't told it to do it separately for each DIV, but I'm not sure how to tell it to basically map the first item in the array to the first DIV, the second item to the second DIV, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently changing the width of all div's in each iteration. `$('div')` selects every div, every time. You could use the index parameter that is passed to your iterator callback:

```
$.each(percentages, function(i) {
    $('div').eq(i).width(this + '%');
});
```

You could also flip it the other way around: access all div elements, set their width and use the callback function that `.width` accepts to yield one width for each element:

```
$('div').width(function(i) { 
    return percentages[i] + '%'; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized it was selecting every DIV, I just didn't know how to write it so that it would only select the one I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just now Edit..

Get Each Div and set Width.. you code set a last width % to all of the Divs in the HTML
Just give Width to Individual Div

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var percentages = [50,25,100,75,100,25];

    $.each(percentages, function(i) {
        $('#d' + (i+1)).width(percentages[i] + '%');
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='d1'></div>
<div id='d2'></div>
<div id='d3'></div>
<div id='d4'></div>
<div id='d5'></div>
<div id='d6'></div>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jkt5w/1/)